Arm twist breaks during animation
I made a character rig and for the forearms, there are two bones. One copies the location, rotation and scale of the IK Forearm bone, and the second one has a copy rotation only on the y axis in local space - local space as well as damped track to the Hand Ik Controller.
While testing and posing the character on it’s rest pose, there are no issues present, but during animation this happens:

I’ve always ran into this issue in Blender and so far I haven’t seen anyone capable of solving it. Copy rotation constraints break every single time during animation and I don’t know why.
Any help would be appreciated.

Is there any reason that bone will ever need to twist?

Ofc! It's the forearm bone and that is need for proper wrist rotation.

It's a bug and has been fixed in 4.2.
https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/4.2/animation_rigging/#constraints

The behavior of the “Limit Rotation” constraint has been modified to fix a bug (Bug Report, ed2408400d). In older versions the constrained object would flip back to the minimum when an angle is higher than 180º. This is now changed so values higher than 180º are supported. This means a minimum of 90º and a maximum of 270º now works properly. Also instead of snapping back to the minimum, the rotation will snap to the closest boundary when the rotation is out of the allowed range. Rigs relying on the old behavior of snapping back to the minimum might not work as expected. "

This makes so much more sense now. It really made no sense why it couldn’t go over 180º and it was causing all sorts of difficulties.
